# Why are my coordinates undefined only inside my circle definition?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a set of circles defined as

```
 nodes = [{
        x: xRange(xvalue),
        y: yRange(getY(xvalue)),
        ... 
}]

vis.selectAll(".nodes")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return d.x;

        (coordinate display)
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .attr("r", "7px")
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("transform", function (p) {
        return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
    })
```

The problem that I am having with these circles is that the coordinates taken from `nodes` are undefined when the circles are being defined, despite being defined everywhere else. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/qzbhLe0d/9/) is a test case to represent this problem, where the coordinates of one of the dots should be displayed, but isn't, since it seems to be undefined. To prove that the axes work, I have placed a dot in the first quadrant of the graph. Is there any reason for why this is happening?

Comment: It's not undefined, but you `return` from the function before the code that's displaying the values so it's never executed. https://jsfiddle.net/qzbhLe0d/10/

Comment: Note that if the values *were* undefined, and the code that printed them would run, you'd see "undefined" both in the console and in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning before you run the logic :

```
.attr("cx", function (d) {
        return d.x;
        (coordinate display)
    })
```

change to :

```
.attr("cx", function (d) {
           (coordinate display)
           return d.x;
        })
```